# New to writing MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I'm brand new to writing queries in MySQL, and for some reason I can't grasp the concept very well.

I have a two tables, one called Video_Recordings, and one called Video_Categories. Video_Recordings consists of movie titles with category (genre) names. Video_Categories consists of the names of the different genres.

So, I need to write a query that will display how many films are in each category.

I've entered the query:

```
select * from Video_Recordings vr, Video_Categories vc
where vr.category=vc.name
```

Which groups all of the movie titles by category seemingly, but how do I query it to count the number of recordings in each category?

Comment: Look into `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the query by category using `group by vc.name`.  Then add count(*) to the select list, which counts the number of rows per group.

```
select vc.name, count(*) as NumberOfRecordings
from Video_Recordings vr
inner join Video_Categories vc on vr.category=vc.name
group by vc.name
```

Note that (at least for the OP example) you don't need the join, since the recordings table already contains the category name.  The following should produce the same result:

```
select category, count(*) as NumberOfRecordings
from Video_Recordings
group by category
```

Comment: What is NumberOfRecordings exactly? Is that where the count is being kept?

Comment: @user1795374 "NumberOfRecordings" is just an alias -- it's not necessary to the query, but you may want it to produce a "friendly" column header.  If you leave it out, then the column will be unnamed.

Comment: @user1795374 as for where it's being kept -- aggregate functions like `count` work in conjunction with the `group by` clause.  Thus `count(*)` sums up the number of rows in each group.

Comment: Please don't use implicit joins in the `where` clause. Use explicit `JOIN`s in the from part.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've updated, although my intent was to preserve the OP's syntax to avoid confusion.  I also prefer explicit to implicit joins myself, but I disagree with you that they are objectively preferable -- there is no performance benefit to them.

Comment: @McGarnagle: true, there is no performance benefit - but it's impossible to accidentally create a cartesian product with an explicit join - but it's very easy with implicit joins (and if you accidently do create a cartesian product with a implicit join there would be a "performance benefit" to the explicit join)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Sadly, MySQL is one product where many rules find an exception. You can easily create an unintentional Cartesian product using the explicit join syntax by simply omitting the ON clause, because [in MySQL, INNER JOIN <=> CROSS JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html). Isn't that marvellous? :)

Comment: @AndriyM: well, MySQL again - why am I not surprised?